# String to decimal

Tags: c#

The application that I've made I've got a text box called service cost. This allows the user to enter the cost of the service they have provided and this is decimal. I'm trying to get this service cost displayed in a `DGV`, I've got everything else working apart from this.

```
currentComputer.ServiceCost = Convert.ToDecimal(txtServiceCost);
```

The above is the code that I currently have, is there something wrong that I've done here?

Comment: What should be wrong with it? Doesn't it work? *How* doesn't it work? Any error message?

Comment: Are you using WinForms by any chance?

Comment: Please provide the error that you are getting? Also txtServiceCost is a text box? You should read the text from that textbox first. Also what is DGV?

Comment: Thanks for your comment guys but I've managed to get it sorted now. By DGV I meant DataGridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question it is clear that `txtServiceCost` is the `TextBox`, and `Convert.ToDecimal()` expects a `string`  as input so you should use `txtServiceCost.Text` instead for `txtServiceCost`. Since `txtServiceCost` is a control where as `txtServiceCost.Text` is a string

```
currentComputer.ServiceCost = Convert.ToDecimal(txtServiceCost.Text);
```

But i would like to suggest you to use [`decimal.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.decimal.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
decimal userInput;

if (!decimal.TryParse(txtServiceCost.Text, out userInput))
{ 
    // Throw some warning here that invalid input
}

currentComputer.ServiceCost = userInput;
```

Comment: Ahh yes, thanks for that it is working now I knew I was missing something just couldn't put my finger on it. Many thanks :)